# Saving an array of processed images in a folder

Tags: python, arrays, image, save

I've this code with this function `dense_optical_flow` which output is an array.
Each element of this array is an image. How can I save each of these images in a folder?

```
%pylab
import cv2
import glob
import matplotlib
import numpy

def dense_optical_flow(images):
    assert len(images) > 1
    ret = []
    pt = 0
    frame1 = cv2.imread(images[pt])
    #print(frame1.shape)
    prvs = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    hsv = np.zeros_like(frame1)
    pt += 1
    while (pt != len(images)):
        frame2 = cv2.imread(images[pt])
        next = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs, next,None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
        mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
        hsv[..., 0] = ang * 180 / np.pi / 2
        hsv[..., 2] = cv2.normalize(mag, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        ret.append(rgb)
        prvs = next
        pt += 1
    return np.array(ret)

files = glob.glob("/home/roberto/workspace/TEST/INPUT/intest/*.png")
flist = sorted(files)
plt.imshow(dense_optical_flow(flist)[1]) #this line is just for test!
```

I've modified the loop like this

```
while (pt != len(images)):
        frame2 = cv2.imread(images[pt])
        next = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs, next,None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
        mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
        hsv[..., 0] = ang * 180 / np.pi / 2
        hsv[..., 2] = cv2.normalize(mag, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        ret.append(rgb)
        prvs = next
        for image in ret:
            filename = '/home/roberto/workspace/TEST/OUTPUT/fbtest/'
            cv2.imwrite(filename + '_TEST' + image +'.npg', image )
        pt += 1
    return np.array(ret)
```

But it still not correct!
Error: `UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U48'), dtype('<U48')) -> dtype('<U48')`

Comment: Check out [cv2.imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite)

Comment: you have a typo, is "png" not "npg" :)

Comment: like that you wlil only get the last image => you don't change the name in the loop

Comment: yes @Ivan yoy're right.
I've tought it's should be ```            cv2.imwrite(filename + '_TEST' + image + '.npg', image )```
but it stille wrong!

Comment: Try adding just a number to the string

Comment: I don't understand, where and why I should add a number?

Comment: before the loop you can declare `count = 0` then inside the loop `count += 1` and `filename = '/home/roberto/workspace/TEST/OUTPUT/fbtest/TEST_'+str(count)` like this you will have differenet names for each image => this will add a consecutive number at the end of the filename

Comment: thanks Ivan it works! I owe you.
Can I bother you for one more thing?

What about if the png file's name in home/roberto/workspace/TEST/INPUT/intest/*.png are like "img_001949.png" what should I modify if I want output files named e.g. "TEST_img_001949.png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, `cv2.imwrite()` should do it :

```
for image in ret:
    filename = xxx ## something that changes in this loop -> you can set a complete path to manage folders
    cv2.imwrite(filename , image )
```

Comment: pls check my modification